# GPGPU search String in another one

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I'm looking for an algorithm to search one string in another one, but I know that strings are'nt supported in CUDA or OpenCL natively (but I saw a post which shows that OpenCL can receive a character array like the code below)

```
__kernel void test(__global word_t *data,  __global res_t *result)
{
   size_t id=get_global_id(0);
   int size=0;
   int size=data[id].len;
   // local memory "allocator"
   __local int offset = 0;
   volatile __local int* pOffset = &offset;
   __local char wordBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   // "allocate" memory
   int myOffset = atomic_add( pOffset, size );
   //working with the word
   __local char* pThreadWord = &wordBuffer[ myOffset ];
}
```

I have a lot of big and little strings and I have to search the presence (and detect the position) of these little on big strings in parallel, can anyone help me?

ps: this code was found at: [Using "String" in openCl Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492263/using-string-in-opencl-kernel)

Comment: You can have overlapped (since you cant know which workitem can find it) searching per item and reduce their results in local memory then reduce local results in global memory. Let item-0 search 0 - 110 while item-1 doing 90 - 210 and item-2 doing 190-310 if word is 20 chars. Also loading memory into local memory before this, can be useful for random accessing.

Comment: so, my strings' length is variable, how can I do this access type?

Comment: make kernel launch length variable then. I don't know maybe you use dynamic parallelism and let the gpu cores decide how far they compute?