# How can I do a word frequency counter with OpenCL?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I'm starting with OpenCL and would like to develop a word frequency counter from a given text.

I have a vector of words, same or different words, and now I want to "reduce" with OpenCL and know the frequency of any word in my vector. I need to do this in OpenCL, however I haven't found a frequency counter in OpenCL anywhere(even for integers or other data types), so I don't know where to start solving this.

So, **how can I do this with OpenCL?** I tried with map, but I stucked in send the map to the device and do the reduce there.

Edit: this is my word vector, it will be filled in by a function that takes each line in a file and breaks it down into words. The language is C++, but any solution in C is welcome!

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vetWords;
```

Comment: C or C++? Pick a language. Also, show how you store the given text. "vector of words"- is that a `std::vector<std::string>` ? We shouldn't be guessing.

Comment: You're right! Forgive me, I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @MSalters The language is C++, but if you give me a tip in C I will remake my code with that.  So, any help is welcome

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492263/using-string-in-opencl-kernel ?

Comment: @MSalters omg, thank you so much! This will help me to start, now I have to count the frequency of every word in kernel. Can I do a vector to store the frequency in every workgroup or workitem and "reduce" then? I don't now if it's possible...

Comment: Sorry, got no idea about OpenCL specifically, but there are plenty of other people on this site who do. But you'll need to improve your question a bit further. Beginners often get stuck because they don't break up a problem in easier problems. Can you count the frequency of integers instead of words?? You can improve your question by showing that part.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::map` to find the frequency of words occurring in a given line as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string inputString = "this is a string containing my name again and again and again ", word;
   
   //this map maps the std::string to their respective count
    std::map<std::string, int> wordCount;
    
    std::istringstream ss(inputString);
    //go word by word
    while(ss >> word)
    {
        wordCount[word]++;//increment the corresponding count
    }      
  
    std::cout<<"Total unique words are: "<<wordCount.size()<<std::endl;
    
    
    //iterate through map
    for( std::pair<std::string, int> pairElement: wordCount)
    {
        std::cout<<pairElement.first<<": "<<pairElement.second<<std::endl;
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/q7PQkc0nhg).

Comment: Thank you for your time and the good answer, Anoop. But I already did the map to count the word frequency with C++. Now I want to "transform" the code in OpenCL to run in GPU.

Comment: You're welcome. Now your question is more clear than it was earlier. Have you tried any code by yourself which you can add in your question. If yes you should add it to your question. For now i have voted to **Reopen** your closed question so that people can start answering your question.